# How to expose values which depend on another value

Tags: c#, properties

I receive a certain category of products from a server. These products all have an ID. The relevant part is something like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

In the app itself, I am also using an ID of -1 to indicate a default/null option. There are several options like this, e.g. an ID of -2 for "use the same as parent". At first I checked this in the most primitive way.

```
if(product.Id == -1)
```

That is not really clean code, so I changed it to a bool property on the product:

```
public bool IsDefault
{
    get { return Id == -1; }
}
```

Then I noticed that, as the whole class is immutable, this bool can just be an auto-property which can already be assigned on construction.

```
bool isDefault = id == -1;
Product product = new Product(id, isDefault);
```

Right at the moment I tried an approach of using an interface and having an own implementation for the default product, like this:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    int Id{get;}
    bool IsDefault{get;}
}


public class Product : IProduct
{
    public Product(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public bool IsDefault { get{ return false; } }
}


public class DefaultProduct : IProduct
{
    public int Id { get{ return -1; }
    public bool IsDefault { get{ return true; } }
}
```

Now, the last three examples (check in property / constructor parameter / interface implementations)  all seem equally "clean" to me and I don't see any advantage one would have over the others.

Is there any good argument (*apart* from personal opinion) to prefer one over the others?

Comment: The last one won't wok properly, because `DefaultProduct` and `Product` aren't co-variant with each other; however they're co-variant with `IProduct`, but this will force you to use `IProduct` everywhere in your code and never can you truly use the actual references. I imagine that will turn into a mess after the end. I would prefer that you had a private bool named `_isDefault` which you set in the constructor based on the id, rather than passing the bool to the constructor. That way you don't have to worry about each place you construct `Product`.

Comment: @Bauss A)using IProduct everywhere would be called programming to an interface instead of an implementation, which is actually considered clean, object-oriented code (and I concur). B) Setting a bool in the constructor _seems_ like doing work in the constructor, which would not be considered clean, object-oriented code. C) I don't understand how a private bool will help me with something I want to expose? Why not `{get; private set;}` property?

Comment: Yeah, sorry I haven't been writing C# in a while. `{ get; private set; }` was what I was after. Whether using interfaces everywhere is clean or not, really depends on your implementation, but in that case wouldn't it be a waste to have multiple classes if all you're ever using is their interface anyway? In that case you might as well just have had one class in the first place. Doing stuff in the constructor has virtually no overhead that you'll ever see. Especially when you're only setting a single boolean value. All you'd have to do is `Product(int id) { Id = id; IsDefault = Id == -1; }`

Comment: "wouldn't it be a waste [...]" I don't think anybody is gonna cry over the HDD space for a .cs file, a couple of bytes in memory or CPU cycles.
 "[...] to have multiple classes if all you're ever using is their interface anyway?" Well... I mean... isn't that the _whole point_ of interfaces? That you can use multiple classes as the same thing?

Comment: Also, i guess I should have pointed that out before, but there are several types of "default" products, e.g. a "UseTheSameAsParent" with `Id==-2`, so using a real (language-) default is not possible. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is always easier said than done, the answer came with reevaluating basic assumptions about what certain things actually are and/or represent.

An ID X points to a product with the ID X. That is the purpose of that ID and using it for a different purpose is abusing it. So

```
if(product.Id == -1)
```

And

```
public bool IsDefault
{
    get { return Id == -1; }
}
```

Are both *semantically* wrong. `isDefault` is a different part of the configuration of the class.

It being **part of the configuration** of the class is also the reason to dismiss the last option. A new class should encapsulate new behaviour. In order to achieve **the same behaviour**, just for **a different configuration**, the class should be created with just that, **a different configuration**.

Now, there is the tempting solution of putting `IsDefault = id == -1;` in the constructor. However, this would violate SRP. The one reason why the `Product` class should change is if **what a product does** changes. If tomorrow the ID for a default product changes to -32, there is no change in what the product does.

However, I have a class `ProductParser` where `Product`s are created. The one reason why *that* class should change is if **how products are parsed from the server to my app** changes - and that is exactly the change we would have then.

So, according to clean code, there is only one correct approach here: Determine `isDefault` wherever it is created and pass it to the constructor of `Product`, which keeps it as an immutable value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Default version of a product.

You can create constructor without parameters to create default object.

Comment: It is nice that you know that, but I'm afraid this is not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it, and overcomplicating it with the interface.

I would set IsDefault in the constructor based on the passed Id parameter. And maybe even add a default value to that, so that you can instantiate the class without a parameter, and it should be a default product.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product(int id = -1)
    {
        Id = id;
        IsDefault = id == -1;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: I guess I should have pointed that out before, but there are several types of "default" products, e.g. a "UseTheSameAsParent" with Id == -2, so using a real (language-) default is not possible.

Comment: However, I'm not sure about this answer yet. Would the bool check not be considered doing work in the constructor? It's a ridiculously small amount of work here, but I _did_ omit other parts of the class for brevity and I feel like something like this would get out of hand quickly.

Comment: It is work that is either slow or requires external ressources that you should avoid doing in constructors, like reading/writing files, querying a database, or processing alot of data. Simple assignments is not only fine, but the constructor is exactly where this kind of "business logic" belongs.